# How to enable ProGuard inside ADT

Tags: android, android-proguard

As my Android project getting bigger now I am facing the 64k references limit issue. I read the [Configure Apps with Over 64K Methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)
 article, and it suggests me to reduce the methods count before diving into multidex solution. Now I successfully decreased about 12000 of methods count. 
But I still have a problem that is the ProGuard can only take effect when exporing a signed App for release, but not for development. With this fact, I am afraid that I cannot put more code into Eclipse for development, because when I add more methods then I click ADT > Run, I will get the 64k limit error again. I don't want to keep exporting and checking the result during development that is really time wasted. 
Will there be any solution for this? Thanks a lot for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

This minifyEnable true. will make proguard enabled. but this is in Android studio.

I think you are using Eclipse, which google has deprecated .

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I know ADT is deprecated, it takes time for me to switch to Android Studio. So I still need to live with eclipse for some time.